# Shell script variable not empty (-z option)

Tags: shell

How to make sure a variable is **not** empty with the `-z` option ?

```
errorstatus="notnull"
if [ !-z $errorstatus ]
then
   echo "string is not null"
fi
```

It returns the error :

```
./test: line 2: [: !-z: unary operator expected
```

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Of course it does. After replacing the variable, it reads `[ !-z ]`, which is not a valid `[` command. Use double quotes, or `[[`.

```
if [ ! -z "$errorstatus" ]

if [[ ! -z $errorstatus ]]
```

Comment: ./test: line 2: conditional binary operator expected
./test: line 2: syntax error near `$errorstatus'
./test: line 2: `if [[ !-z $errorstatus ]]'
I already tried, and it returns as below,

Comment: Thanks, by mistake I put !-z together. 

Answer (score 31):

Why would you use -z?  To test if a string is non-empty, you typically use -n:

```
if test -n "$errorstatus"; then
  echo errorstatus is not empty
fi
```

Comment: I get better results on using "! -z $1", where I'm trying to test for the existence of a value.  I get a false positive when doing "-n $1", where the condition is true every time, whether there is a value in $1 or not.

Comment: @jtsnake `test -n $1` is true when $1 is empty because it is equivalent to `test -n`, which is true because the string `-n` is non-empty.  (eg, `-n` is not taken to be an option, but is the string that test evaluates.)  `test -n "$1"` works fine, though.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is the syntax you are looking for:

```
if [ -z != $errorstatus ] 
then
commands
else
commands
fi
```

Comment: Wait, what?? `test -z !=` ??

Comment: the parameter should be quoted, otherwise it'll be an incomplete equation when the var is empty

Answer (score 0):

if [ !-z $errorstatus ]
just put a space between ! and -z, like this:
if [ ! -z $errorstatus ]